# Crawled - currently not indexed (feed Urls) error in Search Console

Tags: search, indexing, console

Getting error in Search Console- Crawled-Currently not Indexed(Feed URL), How can we remove that one in WordPress Websites as well in Search Console?

[image]

Need To remove Search Console error for my cilnvigilant.com wordpress website